# login and logout jsf

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I am using a Java EE form login, and when I login for the 1st time my url is like:
`http://localhost:8080/mysite` and am able to login fine.

and when i log out here is the code:

```
public String logout() {
     FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
     externalContext.invalidateSession();
     return "/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

and this is what appears on the browser:
`http://localhost:8080/mysite/faces/login.xhtml`

from here if i try to log in again, i get http 404 with and this is how the url looks like:
`http://localhost:8080/mysite/faces/j_security_check`

here is the web.xml

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>mysite</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login-error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Just looking at the pattern, is there a way to remove /faces/ part on the url, or how can i do log out when using form authentication?

Comment: What URL pattern did you map `Faces Servlet` to in web.xml?

Comment: Hi,thnx...i edited with the url pattern mapping...at the moment, i kind of came around it by doing this:  externalContext.redirect("/sisk"); instead of using action navigation

Comment: Isn't the first mapping in your XML useless (the one with the URL pattern `<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>`)? Additionally, you should be able to combine multiple `<url-pattern>` inside a single `<servlet-mapping>` tag like so, `<servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern> <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>` instead of repeating them for each pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the JSF servlet is mapped to service a single url pattern. You can map it to multiple URL patterns, but only if you have a need for it. Having the multiple mappings is probably confusing the Navigation Handler which has to translate a physical file name into a JSF page name.

It looks like you're using .xhtml to refer to your JSF pages. In that case, remove the other JSF servlet mappings:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>mysite</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login-error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: thanx guys, i ended up removing the other mappings and only left the *.xhtml one, i had them cause it was just copy and paste from previous project...it helped just to narrow issues i had...